# How big is the power loss of a downwind wind turbine due to turbulence created by an upwind turbine?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, aerodynamics, renewable-energy

When a horizontal axis wind turbine is placed downwind of another horizontal axis wind turbine (distance between the two is minimal), then the downwind wind turbine has a lower power output because of

a) upwind turbine slows the wind down
b) upwind turbine creates turbulence (the airstream does not attach smoothly to the blades of the downwind turbine)

Is there a rule of thumb how big the loss in power output is due to b)? How much does the power output of the downwind turbine decrease because the incoming airstream is turbulent (and not laminar)?

Comment: This is going to depend entirely on the design details of the turbines. I'm not sure we can answer this as stated...

Comment: I'm aware that a specific answer needs a lot of details. But is there a rule of thumb for two average home wind turbines (3 blades, 12 ft. diameter) placed behind each other at optimal wind speed?

Comment: The only rule of thumb I know of is: 5-7 blade diameters between turbines. But that's grid-scale, not home wind turbines. Are these roof or pole-mounted? If the latter, how high above the roofline & treeline? If the former, then they'll be pretty ineffectual whatever the spacing.